# Let $E \subseteq X$. Prove or give an counter example to the statement $(E^a)^a \subseteq E^a$ and hence determine if $E^a$ is closed in $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $A \subseteq X$ where $X$ is a metric space, let $A^a$ be the set
>   of all accumulation points of $A$. Let $E \subseteq X$. Prove or give
>    an counter example to the statement $(E^a)^a \subseteq E^a$ and hence
>    determine if $E^a$ is closed in $X$.

For the first proof, if I let $x \in (E^a)^a$, doesn't this mean $x$ is an accumulation point of $E^a$, and subsequently it is also an accumulation point of $E$. However, an accumulation point does not need to be in the set itself, so my guess is not true but how do i find an counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in(E^a)^a$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. The ball $B_{\varepsilon/2}(x)$ contains an element $y\in E^a$ such that $y\neq x$. Let $\varepsilon'=d(x,y)$. Then the ball $B_{\varepsilon'}(y)$ contains an element $e\in E$ with $e\neq y$. Since $x\notin B_{\varepsilon'}(y)$, $e\neq x$. And since $\varepsilon'=d(x,y)<\frac\varepsilon2$,$$d(x,e)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,e)<\varepsilon.$$Therefore, $e\in B_\varepsilon(x)$ and $e\neq x$. Since this takes place for every $\varepsilon>0$, $x\in E^a$. So, $(E^a)^a\subset E^a$.